# Ubuntu server with independent gnome desktops for multiple users

Tags: server, gnome, xfce, ubuntu-gnome

This is probably a noob question, but I'm trying to set up a new ubuntu 18.04 server in our small office, so different users can access the ubuntu server. But every time each user connects to the server I want them to use and control their own gnome desktops even if multiple users have connected at the same time. I saw people doing this with Xfce but it has the Xfce desktop. Is there a way to do the same thing with gnome-shell desktop?

Comment: How do you want the clients to connect to the server? VNC? RDP? Check [this](https://superuser.com/a/87813/500826) answer.

Comment: I dont know what the difference is between those two. I just want a simple interface for my clients.